# A Hypochondriac's Nightmare

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

*For a hypochondriac, all of their test results are fiction*

Here is my painting, I call it "Bold and Brash".
To get optimal pool ionization, you need to add some of this product.
To register your robot, you'll need to give it an id, surname, and even a first name if you wish.
I will not sell my cane, certainly not.
Don't you dare join that gang Irene, you don't know what you're doing!
More like belongs in the trash.
You'll have to place the wire coil inside to make a proper electromagnet.
I feel like that's common, scold them again for good measure.

Comment: This was a puzzle I had started to make for [Monthly Topic Challenge #1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7352/) but ended up never finishing, hope you'll enjoy solving it nonetheless

Comment: (The whole thing is now finished, I can see how my previous comment could lead to thinking it's still unfinished.)

Comment: Pretty sure I have the mechanism and final answer nailed down, but I'm struggling to identify parts 1 and 6. Without wishing to spoil for others, are these two completely different the whole way through their solution or is their 'intermediary finding' the same?

Comment: @Stiv It is the same for both, and with that hint, I'm expecting your answer quite soon!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A hypochondriac's nightmare? That would probably be...

> ...**[BONEITIS](https://futurama.fandom.com/wiki/Boneitis)** - 'a deadly disease that cripples the bones, ultimately resulting in death', as featured in the TV series, *[Futurama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futurama)*.

The way to solve this puzzle is to notice that...

> ...every line contains the **name of a medical condition or illness** (or, in one case, an infectious agent) with **an additional letter**. In general, this additional letter interrupts the name of the illness, but in the first and sixth cases, it actually just appears adjacent to them:
>
>  1. Here is my painting, I call it "Bold and **[B]rash**". = **RASH + B**
>  2. To get optimal **po[o]l io**nization, you need to add some of this product. = **POLIO + O**
>  3. To register your robot, you'll need to give it **a[n] id, s**urname, and even a first name if you wish. = **AIDS + N**
>  4. I will not sell my **can[e], cer**tainly not. = **CANCER + E**
>  5. Don't you dare join that **gang [I]rene**, you don't know what you're doing! = **GANGRENE + I**
>  6. More like belongs in the **[t]rash**. = **RASH (again) + T**
>  7. You'll have to place the wir**e co[i]l i**nside to make a proper electromagnet. = **E.COLI + I**
>  8. I feel like that's **common, [s]cold** them again for good measure. = **COMMON COLD + S**

All that remains is to...

> ...see that when concatenated in this order, the additional letters spell out **BONEITIS**, a disease from *fiction*.

Comment: Good job! And good thing you're not a sleazy conman from the 80s either, wouldn't want to catch such a disease